# Android - Use RC4 with Cipher

Tags: android, encryption, rc4-cipher

So, how do I do it? Can't find any example anywhere that successfully uses RC4.
Also, doing cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4"); returns a NoSuchAlgorithm exception

Comment: Why do you want to use RC4? It's very easy to misuse

Comment: I want to encrypt/decrypt Video files, and AES won't cut it because it's too slow. Don't worry about me misusing RC4, that could be taken care of after I figure out how to use it. :)

Comment: AES should be able to decrypt video files far beyond real time. You probably want random access, so I'd recommend using AES in CTR mode.

Comment: If you absolutely must have RC4 then just implement it yourself. It's only a few lines. On my system, using `openssl speed`, rc4 is about 2.5 times faster than aes-128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you list the available Ciphers:

```
    Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
    for (Provider provider : providers) {
        for (Object entry : provider.keySet()) {
            String name = String.valueOf(entry);
            if (name.startsWith("Cipher")) {
                Log.d("Cipher", "Supports: " + name.substring(7));
            }
        }
    }
```

There's a few RC4 variants - such as PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4 (PKCS#5). Which one do you need?

Comment: This list is different for each type of device (or at least Android version). I'm using 2.2, and grepping through my list gives no rc4 variant. From what device is that list from?

Comment: This is from ICS. If I flash the device back to 2.3.4 you'd still find PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4 for instance.

Comment: As said, mine is 2.2. Also, another goal is to allow the application to run on lower-end phones - 2.2 and below.

Comment: In that case, refactor (so it doesn't conflict with whatever's in your device) & include the "latest and greatest" bouncy-castle jar into your project and go from there.

Comment: The latest and greatest bouncycastle for android is spongycastle.

Comment: Ooh, nice. It's always nice when someone fixed the annoying bits already. https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle